# Errant error output behavior with perl execute bash scripts on a remote machine

Tags: linux, bash, perl, shell

I have this line in my perl script that sshes into a remote machine and execute a bash script:

```
system("ssh -t remotemachine /dir/dir/bashscript");
```

In my bash script, I used exit code 2 `some commands 2 >> error.txt` to capture any errors that I may encounter and I want this error.txt to be written in the same folder where the bash script is stored.

My problem is when I ssh into the machine and run the program from the terminal, the error can be captured and written in error.txt but if I run the program from my perl, the program is able to run but the error is not captured.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the full path for the capture file.

```
some commands 2 >> /dir/dir/error.txt
```

Otherwise the file will be created in the users $HOME if it exists.